# Laravel display css effects on a php page

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5

I tried a lot before asking this question here.

I am working on an android project called 5.2 that has a folder called CSS under public folder which contains css.css file.
So the path of casacding style sheet file is  :

`5.2\public\CSS\css.css.`

And I have  a folder called Gordon which contains index.php.

the path is `5.2\resources\views\Gordon\index.php`

My problem css effects is not show.

**index.php** file.

```
     <html>
     <head>

     <title>
     </title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <?php

    {{ echo '<link href="{{ asset(CSS/css.css) }}" rel="stylesheet">'; 
    echo '<div class="one"> '; 
    echo ' Hello CSS  ';  
    echo '</div>' ;  }}
     ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**css.css** file

```
.one
{
color:red;
font-type:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

## Rename file index.blade.php

To use blade and rewrite the code as:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>
  </title>
</head>

 <body>

<link href="{{ asset('CSS/css.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">  
<div class="one">
Hello CSS
 </div> 
 </body>

</html>
```

You don't need the PHP tags because blade doesn't require them and blade syntax doesn't use `echo` if I remember correctly.

Comment: I get this error                                                                             ErrorException in 2ea5a3850a11674191190e60310fe68c4c34b334.php line 11: Use of undefined constant CSS - assumed 'CSS' (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\5.2\resources\views\Gordon\index.blade.php)

Comment: yea because whats inside {{ }} is php.

Comment: I edited @Chris Happy answer it should be <link href="{{ asset('CSS/css.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I question here couldn't I use the .php extension and making some change on the code?

Comment: You could, but I'm quite certain you wouldn't be able to access `asset('CSS/css.css')`